Shining near the peaks
The answer is a specific name (4) (9). What name?



Hint 1 (added more info)

 General knowledge: What do they kinda look like?  Specific knowledge: What's the last one?   (More info) I can say this, it's not related to some sport and the order of the colors don't matter (nor does the stripe looking arrangement..., its just represented mostly by these colors). I'll add a stronger hint in some days - the way I originally wanted to present it (but chose not to because it would make it a lot easier).


By "(4) (9)", do you mean two words with 4 and 9 letters respectively?

@TLEontest77 Yes, first has 4 letters, second has 9 letters

The colours are those of the rot13(bylzcvp evatf) but I'm not sure how to proceed

@BenjaminWang I see, but not related to that

Are the shades of your colors chosen precisely? I have a possible answer, but the color shades would be off.

@DanDan面 The shades are not important, it's just mostly associated with those colors (red, blue, black, yellow and green).

@BenjaminWang It's also very similar (just with 2 colours swapped) to this, another sporting connection...

Gubfr ner gur HAB! Pneq tnzr pbybef naq gurl ybbx yvxr pneqf. Gur envaobj bar pbhyq or gur jvyq qenj sbhe pneq, ohg V pnaabg frr n 4, 9 cuenfr nffbpvngrq jvgu nal bs gung.

@JLee You got what they represent! rot13(pneqf). But nothing to do with rot13(HAB). Think of something else.

@Prim3numbah some further thoughts… V unq n uhapu guvf jnf gb qb jvgu gur 52 qrpx bs pneqf cevbe gb Wyrrf pbzzrag ohg sbyybjvat lbhe nssvezngvba naq qvttvat va gung qverpgvba V pna’g uryc gb abgvpr gung gur pneqf ynlbhg erfrzoyrf n sbhe bs n xvaq va cbxre… gur ynfg vf n snpr pneq creuncf. V jnf guvaxvat znlor vg’f n xvat sbyybjvat gur gvgyr fb znlor xvat Nyrknaqre vf gur nafjre ohg V nz abg 100% pbaivaprq.

@PDT Not really on the right track, it wouldn't explain the colors for example. But keep thinking in terms of (pneqf).

Vg erzvaqf zr bs cbxre, va juvpu gur svefg guerr pneqf ner gur "sybc", gur arkg pneq vf gur "ghea", naq gur svany pneq vf gur "evire".

@DanDan面 Now this is very much on the right track :) Try to finish it somehow

When I posted my first comment, I was convinced that the answer must have had something to do with the rot13(Oynpx Evire Crnx va Znhevgvhf), due to the resemblance of the stripes with the relevant flag - I think I got it now though!

You are thinking of the:

 Caño Cristales


Explanation:

 In the popular poker variant Texas hold 'em, the fifth card dealt is termed the river. Caño Cristales (spanish for Crystal Channel), also known as the liquid rainbow, or the river of five colors (yellow, green, blue, black, and red), fits this description perfectly.


 The Caño Cristales, which could be said to shine like a crystal, is located in the Serranía de la Macarena, a Colombian mountain range. So, it is certainly shining near the peaks!


I don't have an explanation why the turn (4th card) is slightly faded, but everything else has fallen into place

You got it! I just copy pasted them and the fourth one happened to be slightly faded so not intentional. Well done!
